# Visual Studio Professional 2013 "Go to Declaration" and "Go to Implementation" both disabled

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

In every file in every solution I open. I'm only using C#.

I have Resharper installed but I can't see any option in R# to replace these VS features.

I tested deleting an suo file but still get the problem in that solution.

Comment: Are you sure your resharper license hasn't expired?

Comment: Good question. The Licence Information screen says "Expiration: Never" but but the About screen says "subscription until 01/10/2014". This seems contradictory. R# seems to be working, at least the features I normally use are.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Resharper Menu
2. Choose Options

[image: First choose options]

1. Choose Visual Studio Scheme
2. Click Apply
3. Click Save

[image: VisualStudio Keyboard Scheme]

If that doesn't work, you will have to do it manually

1. Open Visual studio Options
2. Go to Enviroment
3. Keyboard
4. Search for definition
5. Change the shortcut and save

[image: Manually]